# ReSharper analyze dependencies based on how file used - how to disable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include, dependencies, resharper

Resharper analyzes C++ code and marks classes/functions that has not been imported. Also Resharper suggests to import files with classes/functions declarations.

One problem with this - Resharper analyzes each file not separately, but takes into account how this file used.

Example:

```
test1.h

#pragma once
boost::filesystem::path path1;
```

Generally this file is not compilable - class `boost::filesystem::path` is unknown and we need to import it `#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>`

But we have second file:

```
test2.h

#pragma once

#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include "test1.h"
boost::filesystem::path path2;
```

Now everything is compilable because `boost::filesystem::path` included before `test1.h` and Resharper stops to mark `boost::filesystem::path` in `test1.h` as unknown. But this is not good - if we try to use `test1.h` in different place where `boost::filesystem::path` not imported we get error.

I need that Resharper analyze dependencies of each file based only on `#import` commands in that file. How to set up it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a header only makes sense in the context of a .cpp file which includes it (e.g. when precompiled headers are used, or when the header implicitly depends on other headers), so to parse and analyze a file R++ has to find the corrsponding .cpp file, and process it until the required header is reached. All analyses, including the auto-import functionality, work with the abstract syntax tree which is constructed as the result - that it the cause of the behavior that you describe.

For many headers that are just an interface to a .cpp file, it's a good idea to make the header the first file included into the .cpp file. In this case, R++ will pick it as the context for parsing, and you'll get the desired auto-import behavior.

It might be feasible to add an option to parse headers as though they are standalone files if that's what works for your project. Please create a request in R++'s [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23RSCPP) if you would like this option to get implemented.